# How can I append multiple reports together?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, report, subreports

I have a number of reports that need to be both run separately and also as a group.

I've created these reports and was hoping I could just create a form where I could just append report1, report2, report3, etc. together without creating a different report and making all of those reports subreports.

Is this possible?

---

Edit: I'm displaying it in the .NET WinForms control, but it will also be exported to PDF and perhaps DOC, XLS etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a third report that has the first N reports setup as sub-reports in the header one after the other.
Why is this not a good option for you?

Possibly you could post-append. What is the output format?

Comment: The reason subreports aren't optimal for me are because it seems easier to append in code (if possible) I'm new(ish) to CR and I find the GUI formating controls clunky. This approach isn't unacceptable, just less preferred.

Comment: Preference is subjective. I prefer to do less work to get it working ;)  I would create the UberReport, and show/hide sections like Gerrie says if you need to.

Comment: That being said... It is possible to create a report from scratch in code... But not easier.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I could do some new CrystalReport.AppendReport(report1) or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

use the option Kieveli suggested and show and hide the subreports depending on the user's choice if you want a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Definitively the best to do it is using subreports, less coding, less trouble for you.

Comment: why does this answer got a downvote? it's basically the same as the one @kievell did, just more briefly described.